# How can I prevent bing/bat.js load Clarity?

Tags: ms-clarity

Since 8th December 2021, the bing/bat.js started to include Clarity.js from various domains like d.clarity.ms, e.clarity.ms, etc.
I've never asked and turned on this feature.
The Content Security Policy block it and generates errors at each page load.
On the bing.com/webmasters I did not find any way to turn on Clarity. The domain is not included in any Clarity projects.
Could you please help me to find a way to turn off the call of Clarity from bat.js?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the way.
In Microsoft Advertising, the UET tag has to be re-configured. A checkbox appeared in the UET wizard that allows you to turn off Clarity.